# Python patch item assignment

Tags: python, monkeypatching

Lets say one wants to add **item assignment** to a class instance from a foreign library:

```
# defined outside our code base
class WeDoNotWantToDeriveThis(object): pass


inst = WeDoNotWantToDeriveThis()
def set_item_func(self, idx, val): print("hi there")
import types
# try to patch item setter
inst.__setitem__ = types.MethodType(set_item_func, inst)
assert hasattr(inst, '__setitem__')
print(type(inst.__setitem__)) # prints "instancemethod"
# try to perform item assignment on inst
inst[0] = None # raises 'object does not support item assignment'
```

The question is how to do this properly. Maybe '**setitem**' is not looked up on the instance, but on the class itself to check whether the object does support item assignment?

According to the documentation, implementing the **setitem** method should be sufficient:
[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**setitem**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__)

Comment: Try implementing `__getitem__` instead.

Comment: Why not subclass, rather than monkey-patching?

Comment: Because that would require too many code changes. It is just supposed to be a simple workaround for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the instance method on the class:

```
>>> WeDoNotWantToDeriveThis.__setitem__ = types.MethodType(set_item_func, None, WeDoNotWantToDeriveThis)
>>> inst[0] = None
hi there
>>>
```

Comment: I really have to patch the instance (if that is possible), because I do not want to introduce side effects for other users of that particular library.

Comment: There can be no side effects, as item assignment is only used by you. Or do you override the default item assignment?

Comment: Your code raises on Python3: TypeError: method expected 2 arguments, got 3

Comment: you're right. There is no default item assignment (at the moment).

Comment: Ooops, I tested on Python2. I don't have a Python3 handy, unfortunatlely.

Comment: if I omit the 2 parameter (None) it works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: actually it then replaces inst with a type object named like the class itself.

Comment: What does `import types; help(types.MethodType)` in the interpreter say? Maybe the arguments have understandable names...

Comment: This shows the docstring of the type instancemethod (which is expected)

Comment: Yea, but what does the docstring say? Any hints in the parameter names?

Comment: You're right. The docstring differs for Py2 and 3. For Py2 it is like you suggested, while in Py3 one only passes the function and the instance to create a bound instance method. I'm going to accept your answer :+1: